# SharePoint 2010 how to use conditional CSSRegistration

Tags: 2010, cssregistration

I am trying to use a conditional CssRegistration command in SharePoint 2010, but is not working. Here is the command I am using:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegister1" name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/nh/css/ie8.css %>" After="main.css" runat="server" ConditionalExpression="IE 8"/>
```

The css file I want to load is in the style library as indicated. I have approved the master page that I have included this command on. I would like to have my conditional style sheet load after my main.css that is why I am using the After property.

The result is that no include line is appearing the generated html. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned code.

```
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/nh/css/ie8.css %>" After="main.css" ConditionalExpression="gte IE 7" runat="server" />
```

You need to change `ConditionalExpression="IE 8"` to `ConditionalExpression="gte IE 7"` as I have mentioned above.

- Also Please check the path of CSS if it is fine or not.

Pay special attention to the ConditionalExpression which is set to NON IE Browser, to reach other browsers you need to also specify the `RevealToNonIE="True"`

If you still have a problem than please let me know.

Comment: I can see only ID parameter you have removed from solution code, there is not change in the path

Comment: I have just changed the Conditional Expression as sometimes it is causing the problems...Check it again Dude..

Comment: ohh My miss. sorry

Comment: Your suggested solution worked in loading the css file now, the only issue is that it is loading it before the main.css. It looks like the After command is being ignored. Any idea how to fix that part?

Comment: In which browser are you facing this issue?

Comment: If it is non IE browser than please check my updated answer.